# How do I move an element from list A to list B via the user's input (looped too) in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Below is the code that I am running in python, as well as the desired output. I put it in a loop to move multiple elements(names) to the second list until the user enters a blank. The only problem is I can't wrap my head around a code for the input to move one name from regularLine to FastTrack.

Code:

```
regularLine = ["Ryan","Luke","Chase","Scotty","Brayden","Ben","James","Daniel","Carson","Nathalia","Ian","Dave"]
fastTrack = []
print("Hello, my name is Rebo and today you'll be choosing who gets to \ngo into the fast track.\n")
print("In the regular line we have {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \n{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, and {}.\n".format(*regularLine))
NotBlank = True
while NotBlank is True:
  chosenNames = input("Ready?\nEnter chosen names here:")
  regularLine.remove(input)
  fastTrack.append(input)
  print("You've now moved {} to the fast track."fastTrack)
  if chosenNames == "":
    NotBlank is False
    break;
  else:
    NotBlank is True
```

Desired output:

```
print("You've now moved {} to the fast track.".format(*fastTrack))
```

If not already seen,

```
      regularLine.remove(input)
      fastTrack.append(input)
```

are the two lines that I'd like to have where the input is taken and used to remove a name from list A and add it to list B. It'd probably be easier if I turned the lists into files, but I'd like to keep it as it is.

Comment: `regularLine.remove(chosenNames)` and `fastTrack.append(chosenNames)`.  Do you expect to move more than one?

Comment: And you want `NotBlank = True` not `NotBlank is True`, but you will want to check that BEFORE you manipulate the lists.

Comment: Yes--I'm looking to move more than one, and I had a brain fart when coding 'notBlank is True'. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `input` is a function and not a variable. You register the user's input in `chosenNames`. Therefore to remove that name, you will need to specify the variable it's stored. Note that you will want to move your `if` statement for an empty content higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print("In the regular line we have", ' '.join(regularLine))
while 1:
  chosenName = input("Ready?\nEnter chosen names here:")
  if not chosenName:
    break
  regularLine.remove(chosenName)
  fastTrack.append(chosenName)
  print("You've now moved {} to the fast track.", chosenName)
```

Comment: Smart idea to utilize join instead of format. Should've tried to simply other parts of my code while brainstorming for some type of answer. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Don’t do regularLine.remove(input) do regularLine.remove(chosenNames) and the same for fastTrack but with append. You can put this in an if statement which checks if “chosenNames in regularLine” and if you want to remove multiple names then I would do this code:

```
for item in chosenNames.split():
    if item in regularLine:
        regularLine.remove(item)
        fastTrack.append(item)
```

Comment: I get what you're saying by having input in regularLine.remove(), but I found it unnecessary to fix because of the logic I had "implemented"...I wasn't really thinking. Just hoped someone would pick up what I was putting down. Thanks for the sample code--it helped greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `index` to find the index of the item in the list, then `pop` it out, then `append` to the 2nd list.

```py
regularLine = [
    "Ryan", "Luke", "Chase", "Scotty", "Brayden", "Ben", "James", "Daniel",
    "Carson", "Nathalia", "Ian", "Dave"
]
fastTrack = []
print(
    "Hello, my name is Rebo and today you'll be choosing who gets to \ngo into the fast track."
)
print(
    "In the regular line we have {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \n{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, and {}."
    .format(*regularLine))
print("Ready?")

while True:
    chosenName = input("Enter chosen names here: ")
    if not chosenName:
        break
    try:
        i = regularLine.index(chosenName)
    except ValueError:
        print(f"{chosenName} is not here!")
        continue
    fastTrack.append(regularLine.pop(i))

print("You've now moved {} to the fast track.".format(", ".join(fastTrack) or "no one"))
```

Comment: Gratzi. Means a lot and I like how you applied an exception so there wouldn't be an error if the user's input was different from what the code needed.

Answer (score 0):

Do not pass in input into the remove and append functions, but the variable itself. Also, `.join(fastTrack)` makes it so the brackets do not appear in the string when it is printed.

```
regularLine = ["Ryan", "Luke", "Chase", "Scotty", "Brayden", "Ben", "James", "Daniel", "Carson", "Nathalia", "Ian",
               "Dave"]
fastTrack = []
print("Hello, my name is Rebo and today you'll be choosing who gets to \ngo into the fast track.\n")
print("In the regular line we have {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \n{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, and {}.\n".format(*regularLine))
NotBlank = True
while NotBlank is True:
    chosenNames = input(str("Ready?\nEnter chosen names here:"))
    if chosenNames in regularLine:
        fastTrack.append(chosenNames)
        regularLine.remove(chosenNames)
    print("You've now moved {} to the fast track.".format(", ".join(fastTrack)))
    if chosenNames == "":
        NotBlank = False
        break
    else:
        NotBlank = True
```